# Laravel custom validation failure with a nice message

Tags: validation, laravel-5, translation

I need to add custom validation failure, I can add a message like so

```
$validator->errors()->add('my_number', 'validation.not_in');
```

and an error message I'm getting is `validation.not_in`

What I need is, an an error message like this - `The selected My Favourite Number is invalid.`

I have my `\resources\lang\en\validation.php` configured to put the right message and `attributes` to it. It is basically looks like this:

```
return [
    ...
    'not_in'               => 'The selected :attribute is invalid.',
    ....
    'attributes' => [
         'my_number' => 'My Favourite Number'
    ],

];
```

**Failed solution**

The one solution I can think of is to go to Laravel source code and find a file `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php`, find a function `addFailure` and make it `public` instead of `protected`.

then I'll be able to do things like

```
$validator->addFailure('my_number', 'not_in', []);
```

And when I do it, I'm getting my message `The selected My Favourite Number is invalid.` As expected!

But I cannot change a source code of Laravel

Please give me another option.

Comment: uh, when override the language file in `storage/lang/en`? that `validation.php` and change the message as you like, is it not working? what does `lang('validation.not_in', [':attribute' => 'My Favourite Number'])` gave you?

Comment: I added the validation.php example in the question. And lang is not a function. Did you mean @lang? If yes it is only available in a `Blade`, I'm adding my custom failure in a `controller`.

Comment: did you mean `$validator->errors()->add('my_number', __('validation.not_in', ['attribute' => __('validation.attributes.my_number')]));?` If yes, than it is working. But looks ugly. And it is not the same because it will ignore custom section of `validation.php`.

Comment: sorry, i thought the [facade](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Lang.html) still written on the new docs. on the old docs we had [`Lang::get()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/localization#basic-usage). Its been a while since i used laravel i just had a rough memory on it.

Comment: You are a traitor :) what did you pick over Laravel?